# Invalid date ArgumentError and incorrect parse on a valid date?

Tags: ruby, date

```
dates = ["11/12/08 10:47", "11/12/08 13:23", "11/12/08 13:30", 
         "11/25/08 19:21", "2/2/09 11:29", "11/12/08 15:00"]
```

This throws an invalid argument error:

```
dates.each do |date|
  d = Date.parse(date)
  d.mon
end
 #=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

But take the first date in `dates` and this is the output:

```
d = Date.parse('11/12/08 10:47')
puts d.mon
 #=> #<Date: 2011-12-08 ((2455904j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
 #=> 12 but this should be 11
```

1. In the first example why am I getting an invalid ArgumentError?
2. In example 2, why is the `Date` object created with the `mon` and `day` swapped?

Comment: Probably it is taking as `yyyy-mm-dd` format and looking for the same.

Comment: So i guess `11/25/08` gave you the error.Because there is no 25th month

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given your input, `Date.parse` is parsing your dates assuming they are in the format `YY/MM/DD`, so when it try to parse `11/25/08` it fails because `25` is not a valid month:

```
d = Date.parse('11/12/08 10:47')
d.year
# => 2011
d.month
# => 12
d.day
# => 8

Date.parse('11/25/08 19:21')
# ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Given that your dates are all in the same format, you should use the [`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) method instead:

```
d = Date.strptime('11/12/08 10:47', '%m/%d/%y')
d.year    
# => 2008
d.month
# => 11
d.day
# => 12

Date.strptime('11/25/08 19:21', '%m/%d/%y')
# => #<Date: 2008-11-25 ((2454796j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

**Edit** Instead of the format string `%m/%d/%y` the shortcut `%D` can be used:

```
Date.strptime('11/25/08 19:21', '%D')
# => #<Date: 2008-11-25 ((2454796j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's `Date.parse` is expecting either a YYYY-MM-DD (see also [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for more information) or a DD-MM-YYYY as well but not DD-MM-YY (i.e. 2 digits only for year). The last is treated instead as YY-MM-DD.